# firebase-tools getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND metadata.google.internal

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-admin

I'm getting this error in my terminal:

```
@firebase/database: FIREBASE WARNING: {"code":"app/invalid- 
credential","message":"Credential implementation provided to . 
initializeApp() via the \"credential\" property failed to fetch a valid 
Google OAuth2 access token with the following error: \"Failed to parse 
access token response: Error: Error while making request: getaddrinfo 
ENOTFOUND metadata.google.internal metadata.google.internal:80. Error 
code: ENOTFOUND\"."}`
```

when using `firebase-tools`. This is the simple node script I'm trying to run.

```
const admin = require("firebase-admin");

const firebase = admin.initializeApp({
  apiKey: "MY_API_KEY",
  authDomain: "APP_ID.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: `https://DATABASE_URL.firebaseio.com`,
  projectId: "APP_ID"
});

const snap = firebase
  .database()
  .ref("REF")
  .child("ID")
  .once("value");
console.log(snap);
```

Firebase tools version: 5.0.1

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling, logging in and out of firebase-tools with `firebase login` / `firebase-logout`

Comment: `admin.credential.cert(account)` works fine. I'd still like to find out why this doesn't though

Answer (score 26, accepted):

the configuration has the wrong structure and lacks fields ...

```
admin.initializeApp({
    databaseURL: 'https://<DATABASE_NAME>.firebaseio.com',
    credential: admin.credential.cert({
        projectId: '<PROJECT_ID>',
        clientEmail: 'foo@<PROJECT_ID>.iam.gserviceaccount.com',
        privateKey: '-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n<KEY>\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n'
    })
});
```

you cannot just use the "web" configuration to access the Firebase Admin SDK.

because if this would be possible, the private key would be exposed to the public.

see the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup).

Comment: Not working, using service_account_id ???
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens#using_a_service_account_id

Comment: Confirm. `service_account_id` and `databaseUrl` are not required for managing users via Firebase Admin SDK.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it simply by running :

```
firebase login
```

I also have this error when I don't have an internet connection.

Comment: wow, you're right! must have been something off with my network adapter & my server. i had internet connection but restarting my computer fixed it!

Answer (score 1):

For those looking to initialise firebase admin SDK on **local machine**.

1. Start firbase emulator `firebase emulators:start`
2. Run `export FIREBASE_AUTH_EMULATOR_HOST="127.0.0.1:9099"` to export emulator host
3. Initialise in code `initializeApp({ projectId: 'enter-your-project-id' })`